# Apps script: Missing rows in output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm learning how to query the YouTube API with apps script by following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/1e7htEWRpRM).

Using the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/1e7htEWRpRM), I've built the below code.
The issue that I have is that for some of the search queries in my **arrSearchItems** array, some rows get skipped when outputting to Google Sheets.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<spreadsheet_ID>);
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("YouTube Results");

  let executionTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

  var arrSearchItems = ["attack on titan", "mob psycho 100", "demon slayer", "vinland saga", "goodnight punpun"];

  activeSheet.getRange("A2:H").clearContent();

  for (let i=0; i < arrSearchItems.length; i++) {

    let search = arrSearchItems[i]
    Logger.log((i+1) + ') ' + search);

    var sr = YouTube.Search.list("snippet,id", { q : search, maxResults : 50, order : "viewCount"});
    var srVidsOnly = sr.items.filter( function (res) { return res.id.kind === "youtube#video"} );

    var modRes = srVidsOnly.map( function (v) { return [v.id.videoId, v.snippet.title, v.snippet.publishedAt]; } );

    var ids = modRes.map( function (res) { return res[0]; } ).join(",");

    for (let j=0; j < modRes.length; j++) {
      modRes[j].unshift(search.toUpperCase()); // add the search query to the front of the array
    }

    for (let k=0; k < modRes.length; k++) {
      modRes[k][1] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + modRes[k][1]; // update the video ID to a video link
    }

    var stats = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id : ids});

    var vidsStats = stats.items.map ( function (res) { return [res.statistics.viewCount, res.statistics.likeCount, executionTime] } );

    var rowStart = (i*50) + 2 // row start for the next search query when outputting to GSheets

    activeSheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, modRes.length, modRes[0].length).setValues(modRes);
    activeSheet.getRange(rowStart, 5, vidsStats.length, vidsStats[0].length).setValues(vidsStats);

    Logger.log('row start = ' + ((i*50)+2))
    Logger.log(modRes)
    Logger.log(vidsStats)

  }

  //Logger.log(sr.items)
  
}
```

For example, in the image rows 198 - 201 have missing values when they should be populated.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try changing this `activeSheet.getRange("A2:H").clearContent();` to this `activeSheet.getRange("A2:H" + activeSheet.getLastRow()).clearContent();`

Comment: Please explain how you are calculating the number of rows, the number of columns and the startRow for these two lines `activeSheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, modRes.length, modRes[0].length).setValues(modRes);
    activeSheet.getRange(rowStart, 5, vidsStats.length, vidsStats[0].length).setValues(vidsStats);`  as and option you could provide a [mcve] that is much simple that reproduces the identical problem.  Chances are if you do that you will figure out the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try changing:**

```
var rowStart = (i*50)+2
```

**To:**

```
var rowStart = activeSheet.getLastRow()+1
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

For the rowStart you are multiplying the index by 50 but some results being returned for the items in your array are not exactly 50, therefore causing these blank rows. So changing this to getLastRow() will make it work to whatever the size of your array will be.

**MOB PSYCHO 101 = 48 items**
[image]

**VINLAND SAGA = 46 items**
[image]

**Total = 243 items**
[image]
You'll have 7 blank rows if you multiply by 50

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Dan. Using **var row-start = activeSheet.getLastRow()+1** did work - no more missing rows!

Then, I guess the real issue for me is why my YouTube API query isn't giving me 50 results for "MOB PSYCHO 100" as there are definitely over 50 results on YouTube when I  search for it.

Do you, or anyone else, know why this could be?

Comment: You may need to implement a method by which you have to seek more pages on each search loop using nextpagetoken.

Comment: Please see Cooper's comment @helloworld

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed your comment, Cooper! I tried the page token method you suggested. That worked, but I'm getting a few errors when I want to see more than 50 records. I've posted about it in the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758008